# How to create a Host key in Function App through Pulumi

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, pulumi

How can i create a host key in Function APp through Pulumi in C# ?
I dont find any documentation in the Pulumi docs.
[Sample Host key in Function App through GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox7ef.png)

Comment: Check this document https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure/api-docs/appservice/getfunctionapphostkeys/#using

Answer (score 0):

Host Key management API isn't currently documented by Microsoft and its Open API spec is missing. This issue is tracked in https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/13424

Since Pulumi relies on the Open API spec to produce its resource model, the `FunctionHostKey` resource isn't currently available.